# Django+React rest-auth

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, web-development-server, django-rest-auth

I am using the rest-auth module to enable user authentication on my web app. Though I am facing some difficulties in fetching details about the user. The Django-rest-framework return a key when I post my username and password, while that's enough for logging in I also want to fetch additional details like user.is_staff, user.username and user.email.

I tried to use Token serializer, but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

```
** settings.py ** 

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': '## How to define the path to my serializer ##',
}

** serializers.py **

from rest_framework import serializers
from lms.models.post_models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel    

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')
```

Please tell what piece is missing or if any piece is incorrect. Also, please help me figure out the part between ## ##.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using it along with JWT? Referring to this part of doc https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#jwt-support-optional

Comment: I am not sure what that means but I am creating a token using the rest-auth module. So the URL for login is rest-auth/login/ and similarly, for sign up it's rest-auth/signup/ @SadanA.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it right, in your custom `TokenSerializer` you need to fetch the user somehow. If I look at the code of the `LoginView`, I see that you can use `request` object from `context` within serializer, so your `TokenSerializer` should be like:

```
# serializers.py

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')

    def get_user(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return UserSerializer(request.user).data
```

and then `settings.py`

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'project.serializers.TokenSerializer',
}
```

---

**EDITED:**
This might break your register view because if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/624ad01afbc86fa15b4e652406f3bdcd01f36e00/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L39), at line 60 it uses the same serializer but doesn't pass the request object in the context of serializer. You can make it work by overriding this method

```
# views.py

from django.conf import settings
from rest_auth.registeraion.views import RegisterView
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from rest_auth.app_settings import (TokenSerializer,
                                    JWTSerializer)


class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    def get_response_data(self, user):
        if allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == \
                allauth_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
            return {"detail": _("Verification e-mail sent.")}

        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            data = {
                'user': user,
                'token': self.token
            }
            return JWTSerializer(data).data
        else:
            return TokenSerializer(user.auth_token, context={"request": self.request}).data
```

and then use this view for registration in your urls

```
# urls.py
from views import CustomRegisterView


urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', CustomRegisterView.as_view())
    ]
```

Comment: I had been looking for this for a long time, so thanks. But you're missing one thing in your answer, you need to add a context. I did it like: 
serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
        }
        return UserSerializer(request.user, context=serializer_context).data

Comment: I just got one more question regarding this. This works perfectly for login, but how can I make it work for registering new users? I mean, currently as it is it throws an error because there's no attribute user yet

Comment: your first question regarding context depends if you need request object in your `UserSerializer`.
And your second question regarding registering a new user, that's also possible but you might have to override the `get_response_data` method of `RegisterView` https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/624ad01afbc86fa15b4e652406f3bdcd01f36e00/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L39

Comment: @InigoMontoya I updated my answer to reflect the solution to your problem, may be that will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Sadan . I tried you suggestion but I'm running into an issue. You can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606120/django-rest-framework-custom-register-view-registerview-failing-to-return-toke I created a separate question in order to mark it as solved since I'm not the author of this one