# Django Rest Framework Custom Register View (RegisterView) failing to return token + user data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-allauth

I'm using allauth and rest_auth in my django rest framework app. When registering an user a token (key) is returned, what I'm trying to achieve is to return the token + user data after registration.
To do so I've the following serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.utils import email_address_exists
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
from kofiapi.api.users.models import User, UserProfile
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('dob', 'phone', 'receive_newsletter')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 
                  'email', 
                  'first_name', 
                  'last_name',
                  'password',
                  'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create_token(self, user):
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return token


    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')

        password = validated_data.pop('password')

        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        token = self.create_token(user)

        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)

        return user


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile

        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.name)
        instance.save()

        profile.dob = profile_data.get('dob', profile.dob)
        profile.phone = profile_data.get('phone', profile.phone)
        profile.receive_newsletter = profile_data.get('receive_newsletter', profile.receive_newsletter)
        profile.save()

        return instance


class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')

    def get_user(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
        }
        return UserSerializer(request.user, context=serializer_context).data
```

and the following view:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from kofiapi.api.permissions import IsLoggedInUser, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from rest_framework import viewsets

from kofiapi.api.users.models import User
from kofiapi.api.users.serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset           = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class   = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):

        permission_classes = []
        if self.action == 'create':
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve' or self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
            permission_classes = [IsLoggedInUser]
        elif self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):

    def get_response_data(self, user):

        if allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == allauth_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
            return {"detail": _("Verification Email Sent")}

        if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
            data = {
                'user': user,
                'token': self.token
            }
            return JWTSerializer(data).data
        else:
            return TokenSerializer(user.auth_token, context={"request": self.request}).data
```

I was getting an error after submission related to `settings` so I removed this part:

```
if getattr(settings, 'REST_USE_JWT', False):
                data = {
                    'user': user,
                    'token': self.token
                }
                return JWTSerializer(data).data
```

but upon submitting a new user for registration I'm getting now the following error:

```
AttributeError at /api/rest-auth/registration/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'.
```

Comment: can you show your token serializer? looks like your user is not authenticated at the time it is passed in UserSerializer.

Comment: Hi Sadan. It's there along with the other serializers, just scroll down. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `rest-auth` you will see that during registration, they don't put user in the request object anywhere, that's why when you try to fetch the user from `request` object in your `TokenSerializer` it is an `AnyonymousUser`.

What you can do is to pass the user in the context along with the request in your custom view or set it in the request object like django does at the time of login.

Comment: Sadan, I tried returning from CustomRegisterView  `return TokenSerializer(user.auth_token, context={"request": self.request, "user": user}).data` but still getting the same error

Comment: if you are doing it like this you also need to update your TokenSerializer to use user from context instead of `request.user`. I would suggest you to setattr user in request.

Comment: Because right now, in your serializer I assume you are still fetching user from `request.user` if you update that and use user from context then your login view will fail because that is also using the same serializer i guess. 
So in order to avoid this issue, I think you should set it in request and keep using the serializer as it is.

Comment: it worked!!!! Thanks very much, I really appreciate you taking the time and guiding me through it!